# localization while debugging in vs

Tags: .net

User control's strings are localized by various resx files for certain languages in a solution.  As I understand, runtime loads those resource strings that correspond to current system locale.  Is there a way to have manually choose which strings (resx) are ran during debugging, so I can visualize layout and how language strings fit in controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the current culture to use in the [`Thread.CurrentThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread.aspx).

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA");
```

Set these during the test setup.